# Twitter Bootstrap - Use serif fonts

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for a site design and I would like all of the display fonts to use serif (rather than the default sans-serif) font faces. Is there some way to do this without having to recompile via LESS? I would really like to avoid learning LESS for something this basic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to change the LESS variable `@baseFontFamily`, it's default value is `@sansFontFamily` you juste have to set it to `@serifFontFamily`.
If you don't want to use LESS you can still change those variables in the [Customize](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html) menu in the [docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html).

Comment: In Bootstrap 3 you need this line if you're using LESS: 
    `@font-family-base:        @font-family-serif;`

Answer (score 18):

If you don't mind changing the bootstrap.css, do a find & replace on:

```
"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

replace with:

```
Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
```

If you don't want to do that, add this code to your custom CSS to override Bootstrap's.

```
body,
input,
button,
select,
textarea,
.navbar-search .search-query {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May I also recommend adding headers in there too...

```
    body,
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,
    input,
    button,
    select,
    textarea,
    .navbar-search .search-query {
      font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
      font-size: 2.2em;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you use Bootstrap by CDN or you downloaded it.
If you downloaded it, you must be having either `boostrap.css` or `boostrap.min.css`
In those, You will find:

```
    /*some element*/{
        font-family: /*some font names*/
    }
```

Replace it with the font you want, it's **that** simple!